# JQuery-UI Style Autocomplete in JavaScript Only (No Includes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, rxjs, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Mad props to JQuery and JQuery-UI, specifically the autocomplete plugin, as it is super handy for reducing cart abandonment and reducing UX friction in filling out address forms.  But JavaScript Reactive Extensions offer an elegant solution too, one that I'd like to explore and phase out the use of JQuery altogether.  After seeing some RX examples and the sites youmightnotneedjquery.com and rxmarbles.com I'm inspired to try a new approach.  Besides throttling and debouncing, the question becomes, how would someone create the 'pick list' below the input field?  Further, how to implement in pure rxjs?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you're inspired to try a new approach, then try it! :) - *"How would someone..."* is way to broad a question.